# What does the avg_running column in warehouse_load_history view represent in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Looks like avg_running column in this view can throw lot of insights on the load. But the intrepretations seems to be widely vary.

As per this article

https://resources.snowflake.com/snowflake-product/understanding-your-snowflake-utilization-part-1-warehouse-profiling

it represents the no of queries running (which makes no sense)

But as per Snowflake's documentation, it represents " the ratio of the total execution time (in seconds) of all queries in a specific state in an interval by the total time (in seconds) for that interval "

I am trying to match the no of queries from query_history as well as the execution time of all queries / 5*60*60 to the avg_running column. Nothing seem to match.

Can someone throw some light?

Comment: The definition in the documentation is correct. The calculation is relatively complicated as, for any time period, you'd need to consider queries that started before the time period and finished during it, started before the time period and finished after it, started and finished during the time period and started during the time period and finished after it. For each of these scenarios you'd need to calculate the during each query ran for that is covered by the time period - and then sum them all up and divide by the length of the time period.